# Admin Hook After Post Status Filter Above The Posts Table

Tags: wp-admin, hooks

I'm looking for a hook/other solution to add a button after the post status filter.

The closest hook I found is "restrict_manage_posts" but I need to hook after the status filter.

[image]

Comment: there is no hook to run PHP at this place then you can do it with JavaScript. e.g. you render the button somewhere else in the page and with JavaScript you move it at this place. or you can completely render the button with JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe the `views_edit-POST_TYPE_HERE` filter hook? `views_edit-post` hook

Comment: +1 for @Howdy_McGee, I should start to think buying new eyes